# Should I be serving Django with gunicorn when using Google Cloud Platform's Standard Environment?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, gunicorn

The [app engine quickstart guide for django](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) doesn't mention anything for their sample [Github Repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard_python37/django) does not have anything like gunicorn either.

What is the best practice here?

Also-

[Here is some documentation on the Python3 runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup). The quote that stands out to me and makes me wonder if I'm on the right track is:

> Do not include gunicorn in your requirements.txt file unless you are specifying the entrypoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official documentation you also mentioned

> **The use of an entrypoint is optional;**
>
> if your app meets the following
> conditions, **App Engine will use gunicorn as the web server and add the
> package automatically to your requirements.txt file**.
>
> 1.The root of your app directory contains a main.py file with a
> WSGI-compatible object called app.
>
> 2.app.yaml does not contain the entrypoint field.
>
> 3.Your app does not contain Pipfile or Pipfile.lock files.
>
> You can use other web frameworks with App Engine, such as uwsgi and
> Tornado

You can use the entrypoint field to tune the performance of your app. However, if you do not choose an entrypoint, GAE infrastructure will handle the gunicorn tasks for you (PaaS).